# Can green color of (enameled) magnet wire be a sign of degradation?

Tags: wire

I know that some healthy manufactured magnet wires are green. But sometimes in transformers and electric motors and other components/devices I see that some parts of the magnet wire are green and other parts are reddish, without any obvious regularity. Can the green color mean that some parts of the magnet wire have been degraded due to high temperature or chemical reactions?

Comment: The color change can simply be due to some additional coating.

Comment: Magnet wire comes in green enamel coatings. See [this](https://www.amazon.com/TEMCo-AWG-Copper-Magnet-Wire/dp/B00IB0U9TS/ref=pd_lpo_3?pd_rd_i=B00IB0U9TS&psc=1), for example.

Comment: Copper salts tend to be green, so a green colour in places on the wire could be copper corrosion, but this will only be around the ends of the wire where the enamel is missing, or has been damaged. It will be rough and irregular, not shiny and smooth like green enamel. Some motors and transformers are wound with wires of different colours for identification during manufacture, so it's possible you could be looking at a composite winding with some green and some other colour enamels visible. However, it should be apparent to most people the difference between shiny enamel wire and copper salts.

Comment: One winding is green and one winding is reddish.

Comment: Different colors for different windings is somewhat common to differentiate them. Green is second most common to brownish.

Comment: Thanks to the the comments above, I think now I know the answer to the question.